# Problems i'll face with Xcode after a clean install

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, development-environment

**I have to migrate to a new machine. What parts of Xcode should I bring along?**

I know I'll need to:

- Move over all the certs
- Move over all the project files
- Reinstall xcode (of course)

However, after reading here and there I'm starting to get scared there is more to the process than what I've listed.

The **biggest concern** I have is that if I lose all the derived data folders I won't be able to update apps I currently have on the store.  Is this true?

Is there anything else that I need to worry about besides that?

I don't want to get done with everything then run into trouble because I royally messed up my development environment.

Comment: You'll also want to keep hold of your user keychain, because there are private keys in there that refer to signing certificates. Found in `~/Library/Keychains/`.

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off-topic here. SO is for programming and programming tool related questions, not general operating system questions. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has more details about the types of questions that should be asked here. Keeping posts on-topic helps keep SO a useful programming resource. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite: the question is primarily about Xcode and publishing to the Apple store.  The FAQ says that questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are in scope, so surely this is on-topic?

Comment: @KenWhite I assumed that my question would fall under the     "software tools commonly used by programmers"  or the         "However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK."                       section of the FAQ. However, I do see how it could be OT. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: @KenWhite but my question wasn't asking how to migrate OS's or about OSX. It was directly pointed to a concern with Xcode.

Comment: @KenWhite: but it *isn't* a question about the OS, it's a question about Xcode.  He doesn't want to know how to do the OS reinstall, he wants to know how to make sure that Xcode will work properly afterwards.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Apparently I (and the others) read the first 80% of the question (that wasn't programming related) and missed the last 20% that was; perhaps cory can edit to reduce the unnecessary background about the OS and bring the XCode related portion to the forefront to make it more apparent. (The reasons for having to reinstall aren't pertinent, and could be removed/reduced. This would leave the part about specific XCode information in a more prominent position.)

Comment: @KenWhite I have trimmed down my question to only pertinent information.

Comment: cory, that looks much better. If it had read like that originally, I would't have voted to close it. (I can't speak for the others, of course, but I doubt they would have either.) I think this will get reopened pretty quickly now based on your edits - I've voted to do so. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I know your only doing what's right for SO and I appreciate it. I should have left out the extra information originally. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing really useful in derived data. You will still be able to update your apps.

When you log into the portal with Xcode it will download all your provisioning profiles automatically. Its pretty cool.

As @joerick says you want to bring across your keychain as if you lose your private keys you will have to make new certificates and new provisioning profiles and everything. Xcode can actually export all this for you as a developer profile from the organiser. In the devices section select your team and the export button at the bottom will put all your certificates in a file you can import on your new machine.

If you have apps in the store you want to take their archives with you. This is from when you build and archive, and is part of the app store submission process. The archives don't do much but are nice to have if you want to test the build you sent to the store, and also because the build's dSYM files are in the archives. If you want to be able to symbolicate crash logs from itunes connect you will need the app archives.

The app archives are stored in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives`

In Fact you might as well take the whole `~/Library/Developer` folder with you if you can. It will:

1. save you having to redownload the doc sets. `~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation`
2. bring across any custom code snippets `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets`
3. save your font and color schemes `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes`

There may also be colour schemes and keybindings in 
`~/Library/Application Support/Xcode`